# How do I group categories together in a pie chart based on a count variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I'm in the process of making a pie chart in ggplot2.
I have a dataset situated like so:

```
category<- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
count<- c(1,1,4,5,1)
df<- cbind(category, count)
```

Creating an output like:
|category|count|
|--------|-----|
|a       |1    |
|b       |1    |
|c       |4    |
|d       |5    |
|e       |1    |

The code I currently have for my Pie Chart:

```
ggplot(Distincts, aes(y=count, x="", fill= category )) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

I want to create a pie chart that has counts for every corresponding category. However,  I would like to group all  categories with a count of less than a number (i.e. <2) into one category named "unique"- is there any input as to how to do this? I want the pie chart to look something like:

[Pie Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kYOs.png)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for `forcats::fct_lump_min` which allows you to lump categories into a "Other" category depending on the frequency. After lumping you could make use of count to compute the aggregated count for the lumped category:

```r
category<- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
count<- c(1,1,4,5,1)
df<- data.frame(category, count)

library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(category = forcats::fct_lump_min(category, 2, count, other_level = "Unique")) %>% 
  count(category, wt = count, name = "count")

ggplot(df, aes(y=count, x="", fill= category)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```

[image]